# Lighthouse nested delete mutation is not worked

Tags: laravel-lighthouse

I have tried to nested delete mutation. But it is not worked.

But i dont know why it is not worked.

I have table `A and B`.

One data of `A` can have a lot of data of `B`

So inside of A model, i write relation like below.

```
public function bRelation(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\A', 'A_id', 'id');
}
```

This is not real, but abbreviated version of my schema.

```
extend type Mutation {
    createA(input: AInput@spread):   A@create
    updateA(input: AInput@spread):   A@update
    deleteA(input: AInput! @spread): A@delete    
}

input AInput{
    id: ID
    bRelation : bRelationInput
}

input bRelationInput{
    create: [bInput]
    update: [bInput]
    delete: [ID!]
}

input bInput {
    id: ID
}
```

I first used postman like below.

[image]

Data which id is 35 of table A is deleted. But table b data is not deleted.

Even i changed schema and data like below. **result is same. b data is not deleted**

```
input bRelationInput{
    create: [bInput]
    update: [bInput]
    delete: Boolean
}
```

[image]

What did i do wrong..??

Comment: I think that maybe the naming is a bit confusing, but in a HasMany relation you are deleting the relation, not the related model itself. So in every `B` model you are just setting the foreign key related to A to null. If you want to delete a B model, just create another mutation for that.

Comment: @Enzo The meaning of deleting the relation is .. the result is correct? So it doesnt delete real data of B?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand you... but yes, it doesn't delete real data of B, it just "disconnects" the relation betwee A and B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just pass the id like below and the relation will be deleted!

```
input bRelationInput {

delete: ID
```